# Linux take a screenshot of a particular workspace

Tags: linux, screenshot, workspace

Is it possible in Linux to take a screenshot of a workspace while being in another one?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `wmctrl` to switch to the workspace briefly, like this:

```
wmctrl -s 1; scrot; wmctrl -s 0
```

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way, since windows in other workspaces are hidden. Compiz keeps them open, so this may work better with it.

Comment: ok so does compiz have a library we can use to do such thing ?